# Iterate over template int

Tags: c++, templates, c++17, template-meta-programming, boost-hana

I have a function:

```cpp
template<class Real, int N>
constexpr std::array<Real, N> get_array();
```

and I would like to test it over many types and many integers. In pseudocode:

```cpp
auto types = {float, double, long double};
for(int i = 0; i < 25; ++i) {
   for (type : types) {
        auto arr = get_array<type, i>();
        // test arr
   }
}
```

Obviously this doesn't compile. Is there a way to patch up the loop to make it so I can iterate over the array?

Comment: You want to do that at compile time with template metaprogramming.

Comment: GoogleTest framework has typed tests and type parameterized tests: https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/master/googletest/docs/advanced.md#typed-tests . Or, since there's just 3 types to test, it would not be harmful to just do `get_array<float, i>; get_array<double,i>` etc.

Comment: @PaulEvans: Yes I do.

Comment: @Yksisarvinen: Googletest is great, but the test is just to motivate the goal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you have Boost.Hana tagged anyway, we can just use it:

```
auto types = hana::tuple_t<float, double, long double>;
hana::for_each(types, [](auto type){
    hana::for_each(std::make_index_sequence<25>(), [=](auto idx){
        // here type is an object that denotes the type and
        // idx is an integral constant that denotes the next value

        get_array<typename decltype(type)::type, idx>();
    });
});
```

Comment: Just for completeness, what is the minimal header? (I'll look it up and edit if you don't know off the top of your head.)

Comment: @user14717 `<boost/hana.hpp>`?

Comment: That's an aggregate header; generally I like to only include the part of the library I need to keep compile times in check. Not a big deal though.

Comment: I'm getting: error: 'type_t' is not a member of 'boost::hana' with g++-8 and develop hana.

Comment: pretty sure it's `tuple_t`

Comment: Got it to compile with `make_set`

Comment: @Jason Yep typo.

Answer (score 2):

The accepted answer is good, but if you don't want to pollute your call stack, it is better to do all of the processing that you can before you get to the actual run-time stuff.

The example here is using [`hana::cartesian_product`](http://boostorg.github.io/hana/group__group-Sequence.html#ga66599f0e1f0749daba759dc661946bdc) which is probably overkill for ad hoc use cases, but you could use nested [`hana::unpack`](http://boostorg.github.io/hana/group__group-Foldable.html#ga7b0c23944364ce61136e10b978ae2170)s to get the same effect.

Here is a working example:

https://godbolt.org/z/zKwpqe

```
#include <array>
#include <boost/hana/assert.hpp>
#include <boost/hana/at.hpp>
#include <boost/hana/cartesian_product.hpp>
#include <boost/hana/equal.hpp>
#include <boost/hana/for_each.hpp>
#include <boost/hana/range.hpp>
#include <boost/hana/transform.hpp>
#include <boost/hana/tuple.hpp>
#include <boost/hana/type.hpp>

namespace hana = boost::hana;

template <typename Real, int N>
constexpr std::array<Real, N> get_array() {
  return {};
}

int main() {
  auto types   = hana::tuple_t<float, double, long, double>;
  auto lengths = hana::to_tuple(hana::range_c<int, 0, 4>);
  auto tls = hana::cartesian_product(hana::make_tuple(types, lengths));
  auto get_array_fns = hana::transform(tls, [](auto pair) {
    return [] {
      return get_array<typename decltype(+hana::at_c<0>(pair))::type,
                       decltype(+hana::at_c<1>(pair))::value>();
      };
  });

  hana::for_each(get_array_fns, [](auto get_array) {
    auto arr = get_array();
    // test arr 
  });

  auto result_types = hana::unpack(get_array_fns, [](auto ...get_array) {
    return hana::tuple_t<decltype(get_array())...>;
  });

  BOOST_HANA_CONSTANT_CHECK(hana::equal(
    decltype(result_types){},
    hana::tuple_t<std::array<float,  0>,
                  std::array<float,  1>,
                  std::array<float,  2>,
                  std::array<float,  3>,
                  std::array<double, 0>,
                  std::array<double, 1>,
                  std::array<double, 2>,
                  std::array<double, 3>,
                  std::array<long,   0>,
                  std::array<long,   1>,
                  std::array<long,   2>,
                  std::array<long,   3>,
                  std::array<double, 0>,
                  std::array<double, 1>,
                  std::array<double, 2>,
                  std::array<double, 3>>));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

What about as follows (without boost)?

```
#include <array>
#include <iostream>

template <typename T, std::size_t Dim>
constexpr std::array<T, Dim> get_array ()
 { return {}; }

// fake test
template <typename T, std::size_t Dim>
constexpr bool checkArray (std::array<T, Dim> const &)
 { return true; }

template <typename T, std::size_t ... Is>
constexpr bool checkSequence (std::index_sequence<Is...> const &)
 { return (... && checkArray(get_array<T, Is>())); }

template <typename ... Ts>
constexpr bool checkTypes ()
 { return (... && checkSequence<Ts>(std::make_index_sequence<25u>{})); }

int main ()
 {
   constexpr auto value = checkTypes<float, double, long double>();

   std::cout << value << std::endl;
 }
```